# Get the html control with attribute inside a string

Tags: asp.net, html, render

I have a string like these:

```
String data = @"<table id="_grp:CONSUMER_APPLICATION" cellpadding="0" width="660">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="_headerTable" class="Dark" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="660" border="0">
```

Application Form

sjfjsdkfj














General Data

Customer ID/Numri identifikues ne sistem psh. @#$qwetrtTY45

Current Account Number/Numri i llogarise

psh. @#$qwetrtTY45

Check

MIDAS check error

Surname/ Mbiemerpsh. @#$qwetrtTY45

Name/ Emerpsh. @#$qwetrtTY45Name of the Father(Mother)/ Atesia

psh. @#$qwetrtTY45Maiden name/ Mbiemri i vajzerise

psh. @#$qwetrtTY45";

The string is dynamic,
how i can get the html controls inside these string
and theyr attribute.
Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php. You need to write parser or use some third party controls

Answer (score 0):

You may get away with a few regex filters, but if you need a full DOM representation of the contained HTML, you'll have to resort to a full-blown HTML parser. Unfortunately, .NET doesn't come with a built-in one, so you'll have to either write your own, or find a third-party library that does what you need.